# what does the static modifier do in java

Tags: java, arrays, object, for-loop, static

In this book, there is this example of how to use static variables and methods. I dont understand what is going on. explain why there has to be static in front of the methods and variables. There are two seperate classes called Virus and VirusLab. The VirusLab.java takes in a command line argument and makes the amount of Virus objects, then spits out the number of Virus objects. Thanks

Virus:

```
public class Virus {

static int virusCount = 0;

public Virus() {
    virusCount++;
}

public static int getVirusCount() {
    return virusCount;
}

}
```

VirusLab:

```
public class VirusLab {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int numViruses = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    if (numViruses > 0) {
        Virus[] virii = new Virus[numViruses];
        for (int i = 0; i < numViruses; i++) {
            virii[i] = new Virus();
        }
        System.out.println("There are " + Virus.getVirusCount()
                + " viruses.");
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A web search would have given you hundreds of links to explain 'static' keyword in Java.

Please refer to the following documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html

Also, please refer a text book for your further learning, that will help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I will keep it pretty short

> You need static variables if you want that variable to be shared
>   across all the objects of your class,so that if one of the object
>   changes its value it would be reflected in other objects as well,which
>   is what is exactly done in above example.

Answer (score 0):

A static variable is one which is not associated with an instance of a class.

This means you don't have to create a new instance of the class to access the variable from another class. Consider this:

```
public class Login {
public static String loggedInUser 

public void setLoggedInUser(String name){
    this.loggedInUser = name;
}
}
```

To access the String loggedInUser in another class, you wouldn't have to say

```
Login login = new Login();
String username = login.loggedInUser;
```

You'd just have to say

```
String username = Login.loggedInUser;
```

This can be useful in accessing variables outside of the class they were set in.
Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

try reading this answer I gave in a previous question:
[Accessing Static variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16880291/accessing-static-variables/16880588#16880588) 
and make google and wikipedia ur friend they'll save u time coming on here posting questions ,waiting and refreshing ur page to check if any answers were given.